# disable animate jquery function for X seconds

Tags: jquery

I am using the animate jQuery function to slide up and down a div inside another div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".box2text").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      $(this).animate({   
        height: '+=130' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    },
    //on mouseout
     function() {
      $(this).animate({
        height: '-=130px' //substracts 250px
        }, 'slow'
      );
    }
  );
});
```

What I would like to do is, disable the function for X seconds, after the 1st time that runs, and then enable it again.
Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will execute the `myFunction()` method for every `5 sec` after the DOM is loaded. You can call the same function when ever you want like `hover , onclick , mouseenter` etc...

Try to implement your logic inside my code.

```
var enable = true ;
var timer ;

$(document).ready(function() {

    myFunction();
    timer = setInterval(function(){myFunction();},5000)

});

function myFunction(){

    if(enable == true ){
        //do your stuff
        enable = false;

    }else{
        //do your stuff
        enable = true;
    }

}
```

Also you can stop the execution by ,

```
 clearInterval(timer);
```

Please let me know if you need any help.Thanks.

Comment: i cant make it work. could you implement the code??? here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/atseros/w8qPP/1/

Comment: what i would like to do is stop the .box2text from going up and down if the user keeps the mouse over the window or enters and leaves the box. if you do that the .box2text will keep sliding.i would like to be able to control that... do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: I can't understand clearly.Can you please explain it by steps.So that I can help.

Comment: what i would like to do is the following. on mouse over the function animate that slides up the window runs.then this function wont be able to run for 5 seconds. i guess that would contain it... is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to consider to use mouseenter and mouseleave method.
Here you can try by youself: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rcpP/2/).

Consider this example: when mouse enter start a timeout (execute once a time): after 2000ms animate the ball.

```
var animateBall = function() {
    $('#ball').animate({
       left: "300px"
    }, 200). animate({
       left: "0px"
    }, 200);
}

$("button").mouseenter(function(){
   setTimeout(function() {
       animateBall();
    },2000);
}).mouseleave(function(){ 
    /* do something else */
});
```